PinChange Interrupts proplem with DRO scales
I am trying to read values from 2 separate DRO scales ( Digital Read Out ), most commonly used on lathe and milling equipment, CNC, or any X,Y,Z table.
These scales need to use 2 interrupt pins per device, due to using pulses for the measurement data. These scales are incremental only.
To get around only having 2 interrupt pins ( D2, D3) I want to use PinChange interrupts on 2 other pins.
The code I have so far compiles and serial mon displays the measurements from pin D2,D3, but I get nothing from pin D4,D5.
I am wanting to know how to invoke PinChange interrupts on D4,D5 to read the data from the scale.
I don't want to buy a different board with more interrupt pins as I have a supply on NANO's that I want to use, and will fit in the space available.
Pins require interrupts to read scale value. Scale is incremental only
/*


pinA, pinB are for dro scale 1
pinC, pinD1 are for dro scale 2

D2 = pinA - Hardware Interupt - Scale 1 clk
D3 = pinB - Hardware Interupt - scale 1 data
D4 = pinC - Pinchange Interupt - scale 2 clk
D5 = pinD1 -Pinchange Interupt - scale 2 data

counter1 = scale 1
counter2 = scale 2

*/

const int pinA = 2, pinB = 3, phaseLookup1[] = {0,-1,1,-1,1,0,-1,-1,-1,1,0,1,1,1,-1,0};
const int pinC = 4, pinD1 = 5, phaseLookup2[] = {0,-1,1,-1,1,0,-1,-1,-1,1,0,1,1,1,-1,0};  // seperat lookup tables for each scale

volatile bool A = false, B = false,C = false, D1 = false, updated = false;
volatile int scale1 = 0, phase1 = 0, scale2 = 0, phase2 = 0;


void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  
  pinMode(pinA, INPUT);
  pinMode(pinB, INPUT);
  pinMode(pinC, INPUT);
  pinMode(pinD1, INPUT);

  PCICR |= B00000100;// Enable PCIE2 Bit3 = 1 (Port D)
  PCMSK2 |= B00110000;// Enable PCINT20  & PCINT21 (Pins D4 & D5)
  //ISR (PCINT2_vect);
  
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(pinA), trig, CHANGE);
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(pinB), trig, CHANGE);
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(pinC), trig, CHANGE);
  attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(pinD1), trig, CHANGE);
}
ISR (PCINT2_vect);

void loop()
//
{
  if (updated)
  {
    Serial.println(String(scale1));
    Serial.println(String(scale2));
    updated = false;
  }
}

void trig()
{
  A = digitalRead(pinA);//Scale 1 
  B = digitalRead(pinB);//  "
  C = digitalRead(pinC);// Scale 2
  D1 = digitalRead(pinD1);// "

  phase1 <<= 1;//Scale 1
  phase1 |= A;
  phase1 <<= 1;
  phase1 |= B;
  phase1 &= 0xF;

  phase2 <<= 1;//Scale 2
  phase2 |= C;
  phase2 <<= 1;
  phase2 |= D1;
  phase2 &= 0xF;

  scale1 += phaseLookup1[phase1];
  scale2 += phaseLookup2[phase2];
  updated = true;
  
}


Welcome to SE/Arduino! Please take the [tour] to learn how this site works, and read "[ask]". Please [edit] your question when clarifying, this is not a forum.

Why do you use only one ISR for all edges? Did you consider to use separate ISRs, avoiding complexity? Or, since quadrature encoding never has edges on both signals at the same time, two separate ISPs for both sensors?

Boiled down, are you asking how to use pin change interrupts for 4 pins at the same time, or how to make pin change interrupt work on pins 4 and 5? If the latter, did you experiment with a simplified sketch just for that goal?

I noticed that this is solved at arduino.cc. Please mark this one so no body wastes any time giving you answers that you already have.  Please don't cross post in the future.  It wastes time.  It's the same basic group of people in both places.  All you're doing is showing people that you don't value their effort which makes many not want to help you.

Delta. Yes I do realise your point. I do appreciate and value the community. Been a while and I am rusty. I will be putting the code from this discussion on Github along with the project. I hope others can use it.

The Arduino function attachInterrupt() only works with the so-called
“external interrupts”, which on the Nano are only available on
pins 2 and 3. For any other pin, digitalPinToInterrupt()
returns the constant NOT_AN_INTERRUPT (-1), and attachInterrupt()
does nothing. If you want to work with pin-change interrupts you will
have to either find a library that provides a nice API for them, or do
it low-level by setting yourself the hardware control registers and
defining a real ISR.
As you are setting both PCICR and PCMSK2, you are following the
low-level way, and you are almost there. The only thing that is missing
is defining an ISR that actually does something useful. Maybe simply
this:
ISR(PCINT2_vect) { trig(); }

While you are at it, remove the two irrelevant calls to
attachInterrupt(). Also, I would avoid reading both scales each time
one scale sends a pulse: you only have to read the one scale that gave
the pulse. You can thus split trig() into one function for each scale,
then in setup():
attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(pinA), trig_scale_1, CHANGE);
attachInterrupt(digitalPinToInterrupt(pinB), trig_scale_1, CHANGE);

and the ISR would then be:
ISR(PCINT2_vect) { trig_scale_2(); }

This should save you quite a few cycles in interrupt context, and thus
lower the interrupt latency and make the whole program more robust.

Thanks to all.
I have a solution from the Arduino forum.
I will put the code up on Github for all to see and share.
/*
  Pins require interrupts to read scale value. Scale is incremental only.
  pinA, pinB are for dro scale 1
  pinC, pinD1 are for dro scale 2

  D2 = pinA - Hardware Interrupt - Scale 1 clk
  D3 = pinB - Hardware Interrupt - scale 1 data
  D4 = pinC - Pinchange Interrupt - scale 2 clk
  D5 = pinD -Pinchange Interrupt - scale 2 data
*/
#include <avr/interrupt.h>
const int pinA = 2, pinB = 3, phaseLookup1[] = {0, -1, 1, -1, 1, 0, -1, -1, -1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, -1, 0};
const int pinC = 4, pinD = 5, phaseLookup2[] = {0, -1, 1, -1, 1, 0, -1, -1, -1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, -1, 0}; // seperate lookup tables for each scale

volatile bool A = false, B = false, C = false, D = false, updated = false;
volatile int scale1 = 0, phase1 = 0, scale2 = 0, phase2 = 0;


void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(9600);
  Serial.println("T.I.S.M"); // Google it
  pinMode(pinA, INPUT);
  pinMode(pinB, INPUT);
  pinMode(pinC, INPUT);
  pinMode(pinD, INPUT);
  cli();
  PCICR |= B00000100;// Enable PCIE2 Bit3 = 1 (Port D)
  PCMSK2 |= B00111100;// Enable PCINT20  & PCINT21 (Pins D4 & D5) + D2 + D3

  sei();
}

void loop() {
  if (updated)
  {
    Serial.println(String(scale1*2));
    Serial.println(String(scale2*2));
    updated = false;
  }
}

ISR (PCINT2_vect)
{
  static byte oldState = 0;
  byte newState = PIND & B111100;
  if (newState != oldState) {
    A = (newState & 1 << pinA) > 0; //Scale 1
    B = (newState & 1 << pinB) > 0; //  "
    C = (newState & 1 << pinC) > 0; // Scale 2
    D = (newState & 1 << pinD) > 0; // "
    if ((newState & B1100) != (oldState & B1100)) {
      phase1 <<= 1;//Scale 1
      phase1 |= A;
      phase1 <<= 1;
      phase1 |= B;
      phase1 &= 0xF;
      scale1 += phaseLookup1[phase1];
    }
    if ((newState & B110000) != (oldState & B110000)) {
      phase2 <<= 1;//Scale 2
      phase2 |= C;
      phase2 <<= 1;
      phase2 |= D;
      phase2 &= 0xF;
      scale2 += phaseLookup2[phase2];
    }
    updated = true;
  }
}


Link to the relevant forum page or post?

Did you try the solutions I posted?

Edgar - As yet, I have not tried your solution, but it is something to look at when I add the other functionality's that I want to try

https://github.com/MorryStu?tab=repositories
